# Rails asset pipeline Rails.application.assets.instance_variable_get('@environment') returns nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, assets

I am trying to compile javascript dynamically and then adding it to the sprockets store so it is available. Everywhere I researched suggested the below code to register the javascript:

```
env = Rails.application.assets.is_a?(Sprockets::Index) ? Rails.application.assets.instance_variable_get('@environment') : Rails.application

Rails.application.config.assets.digests[file_name] = env[file_name].digest_path
```

in production, `Rails.application.assets.instance_variable_get('@environment')` always returns nil, is there something I am doing wrong? or should I be adding something else?

Comment: Anyone can answer please?

Answer (score 7):

Rails.application.assets itself is an instance of Sprockets::Environment 
 @environment' is a variable of assets_manifest, that belongs to Rails.application,  like this:

`Rails.application.instance_variable_get('@assets_manifest').instance_variable_get('@environment')`

I got similar problems with RAILS 3.2.15,
but it was  Rails.application.assets returns nil
`quiet_assets.rb:4:in`': undefined method `logger=' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)`

the issued line was 
`Rails.application.assets.logger = Logger.new('logger.log')`

I back to Rails console,  and find  Rails.application.assets just returned nil.

I fix this issue by this step:

1. include two gem in your Gemfile in case you don't have it.
   gem 'sprockets'
   gem 'sprockets-rails'
2. find the file cause the issue ,  and initial your assets object.
   you can also put that in application.rb ,  in my case I put it in  config/initializers/quiet_assets.rb , before I refer to logger.

   add this line:

   `Rails.application.assets = Sprockets::Environment.new`

   before this issued line:

   `Rails.application.assets.logger = Logger.new('logger.log')`
3. in application.rb   , remember  have activate assets pipeline . 
   `config.assets.enabled = true`
4. for production  you may need to set config.assets.compile = true

hope this helps somehow

Comment: Genius! < throws celebratory confetti >

Answer (score 0):

Build it yourself (which is needed for new versions)

```
env = Sprockets::Railtie.build_environment(Rails.application)
```